# How can I merge multiple neo4j collections into the 1?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have the following collections of different events in my app, there were some things in my query and business logic that made me seperate the different types of events into seperate collections:

NOTE: The collections have different nodes / rels being returned. E.g both collections may have `:User` returned, but only 1 might have a new message notification.

**FriendEvents**: `[ {  id: 'friend_id', status: 'new_friend', otherNode: {} } ]`

`WITH { event: newContactRequest, contactUser: contactUser } as contactEvents`

**MutualFriendEvents**: `[ { id: 'mutual_id' status: 'new_mutual_friend_request', differentNode: {} } ]`

`WITH { event: newMutualContactRequest, contactUser: mutualContactUser } as mutualContactEvents`

---

The above are the collections I have being returned. Here is how I am collecting the events:

```
COLLECT(distinct contactEvents) as contactEvents, collect(distinct mutualContactEvents) as mutualContactEvents
```

---

How can I do: `return allActivitiesInTheOneList = contactEvents += mutualContactEvents` (so that allActivitiesInTheOneList = the 2 merged collections)

**Bonus question:** Is it possible to sort the final collection? I want to be able to sort the end product by the created_at date (so things show up in order).

The problem is that I can't seem to merge these collections into the 1 collection. Is it possible *or did I read it right about you not being able to merge collections with different nodes*?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely possible, you should just be able to use the `+` operator between the two collections:

```
WITH COLLECT(distinct contactEvents) + collect(distinct mutualContactEvents) as allEvents
...
```

That said, you should probably be dealing with each separately instead of all at once (match to and collect contactEvents, make sure you have distinct start node if you didn't have it already from the aggregation, then match to and collect mutualContactEvents, then combine the collections).

Provided your final list is a list of map objects, and the `created_at` date is a property of the maps, you can use [apoc.coll.sortMaps()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) to do your sorting.